# Why are these flags rejected?

Tags: discussion, flags, low-quality-posts, not-an-answer, disputed-flags

Yet another one...

**TL;DR:** Following are some examples of posts which I think should be deleted. Skip to the bottom for the question.

I flagged the following answers and all where disputed:

- Q: how to use z-index with relative positioning?

A:

> to get the popup effect you have to use javascript and probably first
> hide the .popup with display:none;

My thought: *you have to use JavaScript* and *probably* do something else is not an answer, still he's trying to help OP, this should've been a comment.

Flag: `very low quality`, Status: `disputed`.

- Q: How does browser layout adjacent div to a floating div

A:

> This might help. You should add "float: left;" property for the div which has the class "right". Or if you remove the "width" and "height" properties for both the divs, you can see the difference.

My thought: This is not the answer for the question, still he's trying to help the OP, so this should have been a comment.

Flag: `very low quality`, Status: `disputed`.

- Q: move a column ,including th, between tables in jQueryUI sortable

A:

> Try to make to put the class calling the plugin to tbody instead to the table.

My thought: A single line try something? this should have been a comment

Flag: `very low quality`, Status: `disputed`.

Flag: `not an answer` , Status:  `declined` - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

- > > If the radio button value is returning undefined...try this

> ```
>  `document.querySelector('input[name="rate"]:checked').value;`
> ```
>
> this is working as said by Parthik Gosar

My thought: *Parthik Gosar* already posted the same answer with 30+ upvotes then why re-post the same to add noise?

Flag: `very low quality` , Status: `declined` - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it.

- Q: How can I perform an inspect element in Chrome on my Galaxy S3 Android device?

A:

> I wasn't able to ever accomplish this but rather used view html source apps available on the Play Store to simply look for the element.

My thought: *I wasn't able to ever accomplish this but tried something else* is better suited as a comment.

Flag: `very low quality`, Status: `disputed`.

- Q: Set width of relative parent div to width of fixed child div

A:

> Give the width to parent div (which you want to give to the child div).

My thought: That is clearly not what the OP wants to do.

Flag: `very low quality`, Status: `disputed`.

Flag: `not an answer` ,  Status:  `declined` - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

(*Question doesn't matter for the following*)

-

> It's seems that cloning the row doesn't work well on IE8, but the
> original solution does.
>
> Tested with the jsFiddle.

My thought: **original solution** already works. Why post a confirmation as an answer? this is commentary for some other post.

Flag: `not an answer`, Status: `disputed`.

Is the above an answer..?

*side note:* The user who asked the question probably rage-quit by unaccepting the answer. So currently it's totally unclear which post is targeted by *original solution*. (*Which is especially why it'd have been a comment on the related post*).

*Not that the reason for flagging as `Low Quality` is because I've seen the option `This is commentary for another post` in the review queue.*

**Question:** Are these valid answers that should exist? If not, should I have used any other flag? If there is no suitable flag, what else can be done about these?

**Update:**

From the replays, the only action that can be taken according to the current system is to **downvote** and move on.

**Downvoting is often pointless regarding such posts**

Why?

1. Such posts are usually posted by **new users** or posted years ago by currently **inactive users** (*at the early stage of the site*).

Lots of users sign up, post something (*mostly likely useless stuff - as an answer - since they're unfamiliar with the site and don't have the privilege to comment*) here and there and then leave, won't come back and won't care... downvoting those posts is useless since they're not gonna come back to do something about it.

Few posts above are posted 3-4 years ago, users still has 1rep and seen years ago, clearly downvoting isn't gonna help since they won't come back to edit/delete it. those stuff will simply be there unless something else is done.

2. Users hesitate to downvote!! (*They might be smart enough not to waste 1 rep for the above reason?*)

   Take this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/802914/2333214) for example, if all users who upvoted the comment which says that the answer contains inaccurate information downvoted the answer, I'd say downvoting is effective. Nobody wants to loss their 1 rep it seems!

**Question:** So we have no option other than to keep these stuff like *"Yea, this solution doesn't work in browser `A`, but the accepted solution works in all!"* posted as an answer?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253112/disputed-vs-accepted-declined-flags (disputed flag only means that someone, one of 30,000 reviewers didn't agree with your assessment of the post)

Comment: the low quality flag should rarely/never be used on answers, it really has no purpose. Either flag as not an answer or just downvote or both. Most/all those you posted are very low quality answers, but those should not be deleted but rather downvoted. Here's some good info posted by a mod http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260816/3041194 *about questions though, but still applies*

Comment: Unfortunately the "Low Quality" review queue is not necessarily the same as flagging as "Very Low Quality".  The similar names are confusing and there is a significant difference.  "Very Low Quality" flags are for posts that are basically gibberish.  Anything else should not be flagged.  Anything that is obviously a comment should be flagged as "Not an Answer", otherwise it should be a custom flag.

Comment: So the `low quality` queue is for `not an answer` flags??!!! According to [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/2333214) those can't be flagged as `not an answer`, So currently there is no junk **removal** mechanism??

Comment: @TJ I said, "Anything that is obviously a comment", so no, I never said flag everything above as "not an answer".  But yes, "not an answer" flags to go into the Low Quality queue and into the mod queue, so the community may handle it, or a mod may handle it.   There is no bad answer (junk) removal mechanism because the way the system is designed currently bad answers shouldn't be flagged.  They should be downvoted and/or leave a comment explaining why.

Comment: Downvoting is often useless since users who posts answers like the last two are usually those with 1 rep. Oh by the way, the second last answer in the above has 6 upvotes!

Comment: @lostsock IMO the VLQ flag is better for answers than questions.

Comment: @TJ (if you want me to see your reply, you may want to remember to use the `@<user name>` to ping me).  And I don't really disagree with you that there could be a better way to remove junk, but I am trying to point out how SE has indicated how the system is designed to work today (to the best of my understanding).  In the end bad answers are still answers and there is no flag to indicate "this is a bad answer".

Comment: @TJ The fact that they've 1 reputation doesn't mean that your downvote is useless. Downvoting is not only about taking reputation, but showing that the answer wasn't useful / was bad.

Comment: @ClémentMalet that was not the point i was trying to make. See the update. Consider *downvoting* here as *wasting rep* expecting something which is not going to happen (*edit/delete*), instead of *taking rep*.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As @gnat stated in the comment [above](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270618/why-are-these-flags-rejected#comment89797_270618), disputed flags means that the reviewers in the Low Quality review queue disagreed with your initial flag and as a result it was **disputed** not **declined**.

Let's go over a few of the answers you are referring to:

> [to get the popup effect you have to use javascript and probably first hide the .popup with display:none;](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8986252/426671)

You flagged this VLQ, it went into the review queue and the result of the review was [*Looks OK × 3*](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5681044), disputing your flag. This was answered in 2012, by a user who is still active and was last seen in June 2014, so if you downvoted/commented it would be likely that they would see it.

> [This might help. You should add "float: left;" property for the div which has the class "right". Or if you remove the "width" and "height" properties for both the divs, you can see the difference.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25468489/426671)

You flagged VLQ, it was reviewed and the result was [*Looks OK × 3*](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5610468). Again, the reviewers disagreed with your flag. You could easily comment/downvote on this asking the user to expand on the answer, as they are still active.  As far as your thought that this should be a comment, the user doesn't have the privileges to comment, so asking them to expand to make this a better answer would be helpful.

> [Try to make to put the class calling the plugin to tbody instead to the table.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25522648/426671)

Flagged VLQ, reviewed with a result [*Looks OK × 3*](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5664095), also flagged Not An Answer which it is so that flag was declined. The user doesn't have the rep to comment, why not comment to them asking to expand on the answer to make it better?

> [If the radio button value is returning undefined...try this document.querySelector('input[name="rate"]:checked').value; this is working as said by Parthik Gosar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25458429/426671)  [now deleted only 10k+]

The problem here is you incorrectly flagged this as VLQ and the flag was declined by a moderator. You stated above that this was a duplicate of an long ago post but you didn't use an "Other" flag and include those details in the flag.  That answer didn't appear to be VLQ which is why it was declined, however if you provided the details that this was duplicate of another answer then it would have been accepted and the answer deleted.

> [I wasn't able to ever accomplish this but rather used view html source apps available on the Play Store to simply look for the element.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14734188/426671)

Again, this VLQ went into the review queue and the result was [*Looks OK × 3, Recommend Deletion × 1*](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5475537) disputing your flag.

> [Give the width to parent div(which you want to give to the child div).](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24405608/426671)

You stated that your thought was "*this wasn't what the OP wanted*" so you flagged this as VLQ which was reviewed [*Looks OK × 3*](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5554240) and not an answer which was declined.  This is an answer, if you think the answer is wrong then **downvote** it, comment, etc. don't flag it.

> [It's seems that cloning the row doesn't work well on IE8, but the original solution does.  Tested with the jsFiddle.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12514383/426671)

This Not An Answer flag was reviewed and the result was [*Looks OK × 3*](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5673458) which disputed your flag.

Most of these are answers, and while you flagged them as VLQ the community who reviewed it disagreed with you.

Your course of action would now be to downvote or comment to the user and move along.  I disagree with your assessment that these are all by new users who are not active.  Of the ones posted above, the majority of the users are still active, so downvoting and commenting would be seen by them.  Also, even if the user is not active, when others see the post they will understand that the answer is low quality because **you downvoted it**.

Comment: The last one was not a `VLQ`, it was an `NAA`. Please take a look at it again, it states that something doesn't work in a browser, but the original solution works, along with a fiddle. Is that an answer? isn't that a comment targeted at some other post which won't work in the specified browser?

Comment: @TJ You are correct it was a NAA flag which still went into the review queue.  Again this was reviewed by the community and they disagreed with your flag.

Comment: Yea, i'm wondering why they disagreed... :D Still i can't see how that is an *answer* for the *question*, rather than a comment to some other post: Hence the question. What do you think? BTW, Thanks a lot for the time.

Comment: @TJ I actually think it is an answer as well, it's saying _yes, the code works, here is an example showing it does_.

Comment: *the code works* - the code mentioned here is that in another answer, **there is no code in the question**. So clearly it is commentary to another answer, not an answer for the question... :)

Comment: @TJ If more details are needed to decide whether or not that is an answer, then that would be a case to use "Other" and explain all of that in the flag.  From the looks of it, it is an answer.

Comment: `It's seems that cloning the row doesn't work well on IE8,` (*states that one solution doesn't work in a particulor scenario*) `but the original solution does. Tested with the jsFiddle.` (*states that an existing solution works*). Still doesn't look like an answer for me at the first glance itself- it's just comments on existing answers... anyway, leave it :)

Answer (score 8):

I think you're confusing downvoting with flagging. When you find yourself reviewing these answers that you deem low quality, you should ask *"Does this try to answer the question?"* Regardless of what *you* think is low quality, if you answer yes to that question then it shouldn't be flagged.

Now, downvoting addresses your exact concerns:

> This answer (while it does provide some kind of answer) is quickly written, incomplete, etc

Voting is essential and it does serve a purpose. This is how we judge the quality of content on Stack Overflow. You might think it is useless because you can still *see* the post, but I'd argue that it is more useful being seen (if it is *trying* to answer the question) for a few reasons

- It offers an example to others on how **not** to answer questions.
- It can often offer insight on *best practices*. When I am new to a concept and I arrive at a question that has -3 or lower downvoted answers but is okay quality, I usually read them to figure out the answerers perspective and why this is a bad idea.
- In a lot of scenarios, being down voted can carry penalties.