# Is it okay to flag a post differently after one flag is declined?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, declined-flags, flags

I recently flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22372840/2615940) as Very Low Quality, because it asks, "I have this file. Can you explain it to me?" without any research effort shown or a more specific question.

The flag was declined, and after reading meta posts such as [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260816/2615940), [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265764/2615940), and [this MSE one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/189373), I see why.

I still think the question is at best too broad. Is it appropriate to raise a new, different flag?

BTW, the question I referred to has been edited since posting this question, and seems more specific now. I suppose that demonstrates why the VLQ flag was the wrong one to use in the first place.

Comment: Why not cast a flag to close the post? VLQ is different than closing a post.

Comment: @gunr2171 Not if you don't have enough rep to vote to close, as is the case for this user.

Comment: Man, who reads the entire post? What losers. But sure, I missed that, my bad.

Comment: Your flag was declined, and you read through *multiple posts on meta* to learn why, instead of starting a thread to complain? Sir, I would like to buy you a beverage.

Comment: @AirThomas Sir, I would like to accept a beverage.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes, if a flag is declined and you realize that you simply used the wrong type of flag, and now understand what the *correct* type of flag is, it's entirely appropriate to cast a new flag of the appropriate type.

Comment: If this is the case, it seems like we should be able to retract and recast close votes, too, but that's not allowed.  Would the upvotes on this answer be taken as a support of being allowed to vote again after retracting a close vote?

Comment: The only caveat I'd think to this, is that if the flag cast was a mod-seen one, I don't imagine a mod would feel constrained to the appropriate flag type: ie, if you cast a VLQ flag, and it was declined (not disputed, so  a mod actually did it), and you decided NAA was the right one after all, I don't know that I'd recast it - as the mod that declined it certainly would've acted on a question that NAA is appropriate for as well, wouldn't he/she?

Comment: @Joe I should mention that on another SE site, I flagged an answer as spam, and the flag was deemed helpful, but no action was taken on it. I then flagged the same answer as not an answer, and the flag was deemed helpful and the answer was deleted accordingly.

Comment: @Joe Your assumption is incorrect.  If you flag a post for the wrong reason a mod will decline the flag if that reason doesn't apply.  If another reason does apply, by all means flag the post.  Mods will sometimes notice if there is another problem, but they won't necessarily go out of their way to look for everything else on every declined flag.

Answer (score 7):

Just ask yourself "Is it worth it?". Flags require people to spend time to look at the flag, time they could spend to look at other flags. If it's "maybe this question is too broad", don't bother. If it's "this question is clearly too broad, the way I see it", go ahead and flag, even if you flagged it for something else before.

Also if it's "I don't want to have this question here, so let's throw flags and see what sticks" then the answer is obvious.

Comment: Your second paragraph demonstrates what I was feeling. Even though I felt the new flag would be justifiable, a nagging part of me still felt... surreptitious, I suppose? Spamming the flags hoping one would work out was most definitely not my intention, but it felt like that's what I would be doing by just raising a new flag.

Comment: @SLawson: Do remember that there are many many users with moderation abilities.  If you're unsure how to proceed, you can do nothing or leave a comment, and leave it up to others to take action (casting close votes).