# Flagging questions instead of closing them for Deputy badge

Tags: discussion, flags, vote-to-close

After one reaches the 3000 reputation threshold, one can vote to close questions. I reached 3000 reputation probably on 15th April (that is the day I first voted to close a question, as I can see in my close votes history.)

Since then, I haven't used flags, and I doubt if I ever will. All the questions I used to flag, can now be closed. I am stuck at 68.

This makes me wonder if I'll ever get the <kbd>Deputy</kbd> badge... :(

But, I found that in the flag reasons, there is a reason "very low quality". I think that I can use this flag for questions which I used to close as "too broad", i.e., questions which contain only 2 lines of problem, no code, and a message like "Please help me, I need it fast!" or something similar.

I haven't done it yet, and I want to ask If I should do it. I know that moderators wouldn't like it. But then I think that it's only 12 more... Should I do it?

Comment: Luxury problem. If I ever complain having 3000 rep or more, please beat me ;)

Comment: Of the ~6000 helpful flags I had before becoming a moderator, none were close vote flags. There are [plenty of things](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83075/what-are-the-best-ways-to-find-answers-that-should-be-flagged-or-edited) to use flags on (non-answers, spam, trolling, sock puppets), and I'd guess that for those hitting the Marshal badge, few of them did it using close vote flags.

Comment: Once you get 10K you will also get access to the New Answers to Old questions Queue.  You ca flag a lot of stuff in there.  I know people who use all 100 of their flags in a couple hours finding VLQ/NAA answers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Don't use the 'very low quality' flag for these kind of questions - these flags will go to a [♦ moderator review queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260812/what-qualifies-as-very-low-quality-if-not-this), who will decline the flag as it's supposed to be used for questions which need to be *deleted* in short time (as opposed to *closed*).

If you want to get the [Deputy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1002/deputy) badge, start reviewing [First Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/) and [Late Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/). You'd be surprised how many non-answers / very low quality answers you'll find there.

Answer (score 10):

You can still get the badge by flagging answers and comments.

And if you go to the Late Answers queue, you'll find quite few things to flag.

Usually, there's no reason to use the VLQ flag on a question if you can just downvote and vote-to-close it.

But... don't flag for the sake of getting badges!!
Flag for the sake of quality. You'll get that Deputy badge, and even that Marshal badge. Because there's never a lack of things that need flagging on SO.

Answer (score 3):

I think the fastest option is [**to flag comments**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17364/170070).

There are many "*Thank You*" comments in many posts or comments that don't add any value to post. You should flag them as **Too Chatty**.

Alternative way could be using old posts and flagging some comments that are **obsolete**.

Comment: Please don't just do a search for "thank you comments" and use all your daily flags on what you find