# How much effort should be put forth to understand a confusing question?

Tags: discussion, flags, specific-question

I am mostly referring to the question that I tried to help with [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38126645/how-to-update-a-text-file-with-2-iterations-and-both-iterations-should-update-us/38127356?noredirect=1#comment63689697_38127356). Myself, and others, tried repeatedly to understand what he was asking. I would correct his/her English if I had any idea at all what they were trying to say. You can see the question for yourself, but it featured lines like:

> hope you find difficult to understand algorithm if a text file
>   update.txt looks like

```
step001
true

step002
true

step003
true
'
'
'
'

step009
true
```

> i have list/dictkeys which tells me which step need to make pass
>   example `stepnumber=[1,3,5,6]` # now i need to make
>   step001,step003,step005,step006 nextlines as fail

It continues like that for awhile. I added some formatting to make it more bearable.

At what point should this question be flagged? I drew the line when he asked more questions in an answer. I try to be as judicious as possible with flags, and I'm hesitant to flag people because their English is difficult to parse. Should it be flagged?

Comment: Wait, Isn't that text from the "answer"? (BTW, flagged as NAA).

Comment: Yes, I flagged that too. This was the easiest to extract without cherrypicking sentences.

Comment: Vote to close, down vote, move along to the next question, rinse and repeat.

Comment: It's mystery to me why you would spend time dealing with that question. You must have a lot of time on your hands.

Comment: @torazaburo honestly? I'm developing a heavy duty analysis suite that runs very, very slowly so I often have extra time on my hands. But yeah, there are other people that are much more deserving of assistance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, we have a special close reason for those kind of questions: *Unclear what you're asking*.

> Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Just click: flag > **Should be closed ...** > **Unclear what you're asking**.

Comment: What's the difference between that and very low quality? The question *is* of very low quality, and it's also unclear what they're asking.

Comment: @Ares Very Low Quality flags for *questions* are handled by ♦ moderators (see [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260812/what-qualifies-as-very-low-quality-if-not-this)) instead of the review queues. The question doesn't need to be deleted immediately; we want to give the OP a chance to improve his/her question.

Comment: That distinction is *not clear*. If I'm gonna require a moderator to look at it by flagging as VLQ, I want to know it. Especially since Very Low Quality is on the first level of the flag list. It does *not* say that a moderator will get involved if you flag as VLQ. Plus, without that clarification, it looks like an appropriate flag to apply.

Comment: Actually, VLQ flags ain't handled by moderators anymore. They go to queue's first, and if it's not handled in a timely manner there, then it goes to the mod queue.

Answer (score 4):

How much? None.If the asker can't be bothered to compose a clear question, why should you be bothered trying to usrestand it to answer it?