# Low-quality flag - How low?

Tags: discussion, questions, flags, low-quality-posts

Stack Overflow is a strong community constructing questions that will assist anybody looking for an answer online or on the site. I used the word constructing on purpose, every question is unique in it's way and must be easily readable - and if a question doesn't stand the standards it's down voted, marked accordingly, or even removed. **But what if, the question is easily readable, answerable, and doesn't contain a duplicate, but still is of a very low quality**. Down-voting will still let it stay on the site and come in the way when someone is looking for an answer.

I'm discussing this because recently I've come across a user who opens a question about anything, and for some reason he's still not blocked from asking questions. An example that anyone programming for a few weeks can relate to, "Why doesn't my Java class work?", and then when you open his snippet you can see that he didn't declare a constructor. Or, if you've programmed in AngularJS I'll give you a much better and actual example. One of his questions was about how to change a $scope variable on click, and another question is how to display a $scope variable from a list. Those two questions are almost the same thing and he just couldn't bother looking for answers or learning the language first.

Those two questions are properly formed, he included code that didn't work - but they are still of a very, very low quality, which could have been solved without filling the questions database with them.

**Why isn't there a flag purely for questions of low quality? Yes, there is one, but the description doesn't match what I'm saying.**

> This question has *severe formatting* or *content problems*. This question is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.

The questions I'm discussing here have no formatting or content problems. They are about real code, which really doesn't work, but is generally of a low level.

**What do you think? Are the questions I'm talking about worth flagging low quality although they don't have a 'formatting or content' problems? What's your position on 'content problems', does this in your opinion fall under the description of the LQ flag?**

Comment: Sounds like a candidate for downvoting but not flagging. Downvotes are a strong signal that an answer is not to be trusted.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I don't know if you read the whole thing but I meant the questions themselves, of a low quality. Not the answers. Questions that are properly formed, including code and exact description of a problem, but the questions are about very basic things.

Comment: I didn’t read closely enough. No, those questions don’t feel like good candidates for „low quality“ flags either - as much as I hate them, too, and would like to burn them on the spot. I would expect those flags would get rejected because being lazy doesn’t fit the „low quality“ criteria AFAIK. I’m not sure how the flag works these days, though, what criteria are used to evaluate them, etc., perhaps someone with more knowledge can chime in.

Comment: @gnat Different things, what you marked as duplicate is about "you could have used google". For a code of java class that doesn't include a constructor you can't google, but it's still of a low quality (as also mentioned in the example in the question)

Comment: @Pekka웃 Sure, down votes might indicate an answer that is not correct. There's no way of knowing whether a down voter has the slightest clue about the subject matter. I have had answers down voted on things that I consider trivial and have 15+ years of experience with. Javascript questions are terrible for that: totally clueless people down voting correct answers. I completely avoid Javascript questions now - total waste of time. I think many others avoid them too, judging by the atrocious quality of many Javascript answers.

Comment: How about simplifying and de-annoyifying the "StackOverflow policing" to have one core rule: can a given question/answer possibly help someone? If so, do not downvote or close. How does that sound?

Comment: Regarding "see that he didn't declare a constructor" - doesn't that sound helpful for that person trying to learn Java? What for you is lack of minimal understanding, could save hours for the asker who got stuck...

Comment: @KarolDepka for one second I didn't use the phrase lack of minimal understanding, and the asker needs to be learning the language and looking for the error himself before posting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We used to have a 'Lacks minimal understanding' close reason. As explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/217901/295232) it was being misused and sort of separated into two reasons:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

The latter one is sometimes used for the cases you describe (especially the part *this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers*). Note that users with 3000 reputation can always use a custom off-topic reason in their close vote, but this is not an option for you.

---

> Why isn't there a flag purely for questions of low quality? Yes, there is one, but the description doesn't match what I'm saying.

Indeed, that flag is for [questions which need immediate attention from ♦ moderators](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260816/4751173).

Comment: Yeah. The examples the OP cites should easily fall under one of the two existing close reasons.